Android 8 Build Fails with "ANDROID_DATA not set and /data does not exist" Error
I am attempting to build AOSP 8, specifically build android-8.0.0_r22 using lunch 31.
About half way through the build, I have encountered some kind of error where the ANDROID_DATA directory cannot be found.
The error is consistent between running make on my machine running Ubuntu 22.04, and also when running the build in the provided docker container running Ubuntu 14.04 AOSP Development Setup for 2.3-8.0. It's possible my problem is due to setup, but I've tried to follow the instructions closely.
My issue is similar to this other SO post Problem Compiling AOSP with Ubuntu.
Sections of the log that (I think) are relevant follow:
me@0827a715fc7f:/src$ m -j1                                          
make: Entering directory `/src'                                         
============================================                            
...
PLATFORM_VERSION=8.0.0                                                  
...
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-6.5.0-21-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty    
...
============================================                            
...
[  0% 2/30419] build out/target/pr...termediates/oat/arm64/package.odex 
FAILED: out/target/product/taimen/obj/APPS/KeyChain_intermediates/oat/ar
m64/package.odex                                                        
...           
dex2oatd F 04-01 17:37:21  1279  1279 utils.cc:761] ANDROID_DATA not set
 and /data does not exist 

Part of Stack Trace:
  native: #05 pc 00000000005ea3c9  /src/out/host/linux-x86/lib64/libartd
.so (art::GetAndroidDir(char const*, char const*)+233)                  
  native:   art::GetAndroidDir(char const*, char const*)                
  native:    art/runtime/utils.cc:761                                   
  native: #06 pc 00000000005ea82f  /src/out/host/linux-x86/lib64/libartd
.so (art::GetDalvikCache(char const*)+63)                               
  native:   art::GetAndroidData()                                       
  native:    art/runtime/utils.cc:775                                   
  native:   art::GetDalvikCache(char const*)                            
  native:    art/runtime/utils.cc:816                                   
  native: #07 pc 000000000033e693  /src/out/host/linux-x86/lib64/libartd
.so (art::gc::space::PruneDalvikCache(art::InstructionSet)+67)          
  native:   art::gc::space::PruneDalvikCache(art::InstructionSet)       
  native:    art/runtime/gc/space/image_space_fs.h:95                   
  native: #08 pc 000000000033c5ef  /src/out/host/linux-x86/lib64/libartd
.so (art::gc::space::ImageSpace::CreateBootImage(char const*, art::Instr
uctionSet, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char
>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*)+3935)                                   
  native:   art::gc::space::ImageSpace::CreateBootImage(char const*, art
::InstructionSet, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_trai
ts<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*)                                 
  native:    art/runtime/gc/space/image_space.cc:1610   

My guess is that part of running dex2oat involves creating a boot image, and pruning the dalvik cache, but either someone up the line isn't setting ANDROID_DATA or the error recovery is messed up.

The issue had to do with some kind of bleed through into the docker container from the parent Ubuntu distribution. Going through the same process on Ubuntu 18.04, I was able to successfully build Android.

Try this
export ANDROID_DATA=/data ANDROID_ROOT=/system

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
